# vaadin plugin for eclipse build failure on compile theme

Tags: eclipse, vaadin

Iam getting a build failure every time i try to compile my themes. The compilation seems to work. Iam just wondering about the console log which is saying(in extracts):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.503 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-19T17:15:48+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.6:compile-theme (default-cli) on project admintool: Compiling theme "VAADIN/themes/nxo-fr" failed:  Command [[
[ERROR] /bin/sh -c /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/java -classpath /home/cia/dev/projects/trunk/trunk/admintool/src/main/webapp:/home/cia/dev/projects/trunk/trunk/admintool/target/classes:/home/cia/dev/projects/trunk/trunk/admintool/src/main/java:/home/cia/dev/projects/trunk/trunk/admintool/src/main/resources:/home/cia/.m2/repository/com/sharis/bl/admintool-widgetset/7.6.7/admintool-widgetset-7.6.7.jar:/home/cia/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-server/7.6.7/vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:/home/cia/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-sass-compiler/0.9.13/vaadin-sass-compiler-0.9.13.jar:/home/cia/.m2/repository/org/w3c/css/sac/1.3/sac-....................................................................1.5.10.jar com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler /home/cia/dev/projects/trunk/trunk/admintool/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/nxo-fr/styles.scss /home/cia/dev/projects/trunk/trunk/admintool/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/nxo-fr/styles.css
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 2
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The styles.scss file was missing in my older theme folders like runo etc.

**So in each theme folder there must be a styles.scss for proper compilation.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a theme name which has no hyphens in it.

```
"VAADIN/themes/nxo-fr"
```